# Why separate "People" albums in iOS Photos app?

Tags: macos, ios, mac, photos.app

Why do I have a "People" album and a separate "People: From My Mac" album on my iPhone? Why aren't these combined? How do I combine them?

- iPhone SE
- iOS 10.2.1
- MacBook Pro
- macOS 10.12.3